# Sharing elements between generated objects in ScalaCheck using nested forAll

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, scalacheck, property-based-testing

Started coding in Scala fairly recently and I tried to write some property based test-cases. Here, I am trying to generate raw data which mimics the system I am testing. The goal is to first generate base elements (`ctrl` and `idz`), then use those values to generate two classes (`A1` and `B1`) and finally check their properties. I first tried the following -

```scala
import org.scalatest._
import prop._
import scala.collection.immutable._
import org.scalacheck.{Gen, Arbitrary}

case class A(
    controller: String,
    id: Double,
    x: Double
)

case class B(
    controller: String,
    id: Double,
    y: Double
)

object BaseGenerators {
    val ctrl = Gen.const("ABC")
    val idz = Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
}

trait Generators {
    val obj = BaseGenerators

    val A1 = for {
        controller <- obj.ctrl
        id <- obj.idz
        x <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
    } yield A(controller, id, x)

    val B1 = for {
        controller <- obj.ctrl
        id <- obj.idz
        y <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
    } yield B(controller, id, y)

}

class Something extends PropSpec with PropertyChecks with Matchers with Generators{

    property("Controllers are equal") {
        forAll(A1, B1) {
            (a:A,b:B) => 
                a.controller should be (b.controller)
        }
    }

    property("IDs are equal") {
        forAll(A1, B1) {
            (a:A,b:B) => 
                a.id should be (b.id)
        }
    }

}
```

Running `sbt test` in terminal gave me the following -

```
[info] Something:
[info] - Controllers are equal
[info] - IDs are equal *** FAILED ***
[info]   TestFailedException was thrown during property evaluation.
[info]     Message: 1.1794559135007427E-271 was not equal to 7.871712821709093E212
[info]     Location: (testnew.scala:52)
[info]     Occurred when passed generated values (
[info]       arg0 = A(ABC,1.1794559135007427E-271,-1.6982696700585273E-23),
[info]       arg1 = B(ABC,7.871712821709093E212,-8.820696498155311E234)
[info]     )
```

Now it's easy to see why the second property failed. Because every time I yield `A1` and `B1` I'm yielding a different value for `id` and not for `ctrl` because it is a constant. The following is my second approach wherein, I create nested `for-yield` to try and accomplish my goal -

```scala
case class Popo(
    controller: String,
    id: Double,
    someA: Gen[A],
    someB: Gen[B]
)

trait Generators {
    val obj = for {
        ctrl <- Gen.alphaStr
        idz <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
        val someA = for {
            x <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
        } yield A(ctrl, idz, someA)
        val someB = for {
            y <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
        } yield B(ctrl, idz, y)
    } yield Popo(ctrl, idz, x, someB)
}

class Something extends PropSpec with PropertyChecks with Matchers with Generators{

    property("Controllers are equal") {
        forAll(obj) {
            (x: Popo) => 
            forAll(x.someA, x.someB) {
                (a:A,b:B) => 
                    a.controller should be (b.controller)
            }
        }
    }

    property("IDs are equal") {
        forAll(obj) {
            (x: Popo) =>
            forAll(x.someA, x.someB) {
                (a:A,b:B) => 
                    a.id should be (b.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running `sbt test` in the second approach tells me that all tests pass.

```
[info] Something:
[info] - Controllers are equal
[info] - IDs are equal
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 335 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

**Is there a better/alternative way to reproduce my desired results? Nesting `forAll` seems rather clunky to me. If I were to have `R -> S -> ... V -> W` in my dependency graph for objects sharing elements then I'll have to create as many nested `forAll`.**

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what your properties actually are. For example `"IDs are equal"` seems to say that _any_ pair of an `A` and a `B` should have the same `id`, which doesn't seem like a meaningful property. My guess is that you want to have some data type that has `A` and `B` members (not `Gen[A]` and `Gen[B]`) and then your properties will be about relationships between the members of that data type.

Comment: Ok, right now the property-tests are a placeholder. What I eventually want to test is for every pair of randomly generated `A` and `B` where the `controller` and `id` is the same, whether the function `GaGa` satisfies a valid property. So, in a sense, I do need a datatype which creates `Gen[A], Gen[B]` to test the validity of properties of `GaGa`.

Comment: Sorry, that's still very unclear to me. I think you're more likely to get a useful answer with a more complete and minimal example.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question in the next couple of hours to illustrate it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give an answer in just Scalacheck.  I know Scalatest is popular, but I find its inclusion in a question about Scalacheck to be distracting, especially when there's no reason the example couldn't be written without it.

It seems you want to test `A` and `B`, but they share information.  One way to represent that dependency would be the `Popo` class you wrote.  It contains both the shared information, and generated values of `A` and `B`.  Another option is generating the shared values between `A` and `B` in a class.

The simplest solution is generating `A` and `B` in pairs (a tuple of two). 
 Unfortunately, there are some tricks to make it work.  You will need to use `case` keyword in the `forAll` property.  You can't give evidence for an `implicit` value for `Arbitrary` tuples, so you *have* to specify the generator for the tuples explicitly in the `forAll`.

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary
import org.scalacheck.Prop
import org.scalacheck.Prop.AnyOperators
import org.scalacheck.Properties

case class A(
  controller: String,
  id: Double,
  x: Double
)

case class B(
  controller: String,
  id: Double,
  y: Double
)

object BaseGenerators {
  val ctrl = Gen.const("ABC")
  val idz = Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
}

object Generators {
  val obj = BaseGenerators

  val genAB: Gen[(A,B)] = for {
    controller <- obj.ctrl
    id <- obj.idz
    x <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
    y <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
    val a = A(controller, id, x)
    val b = B(controller, id, y)
  } yield (a, b)                                         // !
}

class Something extends Properties("Something") {

  property("Controllers and IDs are equal") = {
    Prop.forAll(Generators.genAB) { case (a: A, b: B) => // !
      a.controller ?= b.controller && a.id ?= b.id
    }
  }
}
```

With respect to your broader question about having objects that share information, you could represent it by writing your generators with function arguments.  However, it would still require nested `forAll` generators.

```
object Generators {
  val obj = BaseGenerators

  val genA = for {
    controller <- obj.ctrl
    id <- obj.idz
    x <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
  } yield A(controller, id, x)

  def genB(a: A) = for {                                 // !
    y <- Arbitrary.arbitrary[Double]
  } yield B(a.controller, a.id, y)
}

class Something extends Properties("Something") {

  implicit val arbA: Arbitrary[A] = Arbitrary {
    Generators.genA
  }

  property("Controllers and IDs are equal") = {
    Prop.forAll { a: A =>                                // !
      Prop.forAll(Generators.genB(a)) { b: B =>          // !
        (a.controller ?= b.controller) && (a.id ?= b.id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```